# LocationManager best implementation?

Tags: android, implementation, locationmanager

Is it advisable to implement both LocationManager.NETWORK_PROVIDER and LocationManager.GPS_PROVIDER with the differenct listener and then unregister the listeners locationManager.removeUpdates(locationListener) ?

Because GPS_PROVIDER takes lot of time to return the values and sometimes doesn't even gives a call back?

Also, we can have a locationManager.getLastKnownLocation(LocationManager.NETWORK_PROVIDER); in handler with a postDelayed to avoid a deadlock in case there aren't any callbacks?

Any help by anyone?

Thanks in advance!!!

BR,
J

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Hm afaik locationManager.getLastKnownLocation returns instantly, so you should not see any deadlocks?

If you really need to manage your own LocationListeners, it is advisable to first register a Network-One and a two GPS-ones. Use the network-Listener to receive a first location (rough). Configure one GPS-Location-listener to receive all GPS-Updates. Once the location is accurate neough, switch to a managed GPS-Location-Listener, that only receives updates every x seconds and x meters diff. See http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/location/obtaining-user-location.html for more examples.

If you want to display the location on a map, try MyLocationOverlay. It does all that for you.

Comment: By deadlocks i meant if you have requested for a NETWORK or a GPS listener doesnt give a call back i should have getLastKnown Location as a backup. Also it returned me null sometimes. So not really a option. Secondly no i needed current location for a different purpose no maps or such. Thirdly, GPS_PROVIDER doesnt receive the call backs which is kind of strange so have to rely on the NETWORK. Thanks.

Comment: Change of hearts from me. Its correct !!! Would be a better implementation. However you would need a handler with a post delayed so that if you dont get any response for a 15 sec time period. You can shut it off.

Answer (score 0):

Ideally this question wont be valid anymore, since Google finally released newer version of location listeners which would take care of this more effectively.
Link for the same below:
http://developer.android.com/google/play-services/location.html